Reading financial data from a .CSV into an array
I need to read financial data from an excel file in order to place the value in a tabular environment.  Data I need has currency symbols (i.e. $) and commas separating thousands (i.e. $200,000).  I'm trying to read a CSV export of such a file in Latex.  The export to CSV also causes the values to be placed in quotation marks.
Can someone please tell me how to read financial data from a .CSV and use it as an array variable?  Here is an idea of what I'm working with, and what's not going properly.  I would like to import \data[2,4] as $200,000.
\documentclass[preview,border=1bp]{standalone}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}  

\def\rawdata{%
1, 15, 14, 4
10, 11, 8, "200,000"
7, 6, 9, 12
16, 2, 3, 13
}
\readarray\rawdata\data[4,4]


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3in}
\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

value at (2,3) = \$\data[2,3]

value at (2,4) = \$\data[2,4]

\end{minipage}
\end{document}

This is what I get:


The readarray package doesn't seem to support quoted fields that contain the separator character.
You can use datatool instead:
\begin{filecontents*}{financialdata.csv}
1, 15, 14, 4
10, 11, 8, "200,000"
7, 6, 9, 12
16, 2, 3, 13
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{findata}{financialdata.csv}
value at (2,3) = \DTLgetvalue{\myval}{findata}{2}{3}\$\myval

value at (2,4) = \DTLgetvalue{\myval}{findata}{2}{4}\$\myval
\end{document}


Note that you cannot use the value directly, you first store it into a macro (here \myval) and then immediately after you use that macro.

This is amazing, thank you for all the time you invested in that.
